# jQuery Datatables: display empty table message

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

i use jQuery Datatables to display some Data. It works perfect but in case the server provides no data, the plugin gives the following warning: "DataTables warning (table id = 'notes'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error."

Why does he not display the empty table message. What do i have to response from the server to display my message like "There are no entrys ..."

Thank you

**I found the solution for my problem**

The Server-Response have to be an empty object that looks like this:

```
{"data":[]}
```

U have to set the property-name (is my case "data") in the Datatables init-code like:

```
var oTable_Notes = $("#notes").dataTable({
    ...
    "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
    ...
});
```

Then, if "data" is empty he shows the "sEmptyTable" - message ...

Comment: isn't it obvious that the data returned from server in JSON format is not matching the format needed by JQuery datatable

Comment: ok, but what he needs in my case? An empty JSON-Object?

Answer (score 0):

You should return JSON from server with appropriate format, for example:

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 0,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0,
    "aaData":[

    ]
}
```